# Ruby: where module is extended from

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to figure out where a module is extended from in Ruby. Right now the only thing I've been able to come up with is to use `caller` and pick out the appropriate line. Is there a more idiomatic and less brittle way to handle it?

```
module ClassMethods
  def self.extended(base)
    p caller[2]
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you just want to find the name of the file? or do you want to find the specific line number too?

Comment: I'm just looking for the path to the file. Not concerned about the line number.

Comment: Are you just curious, like for diagnostic purposes? Using this kind of thing in actual code could be problematic.

Comment: Well, I'm using it in actual code, though it won't be something I lean on too heavily. I'm trying to automatically load a config file inside a project if it's there. If not, no worries.

Comment: That's going to be very confusing for people. It might be better to let people specify the location directly.

Comment: I'm comfortable with the risks. I'll make sure to add it to the readme.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally go for something like this (based on OP's comment):

```
module ClassMethods
end

class Object
  def extend_with_path(mod, filename)
    p filename
    self.extend(mod)
  end
end


class Foo
  extend_with_path ClassMethods, __FILE__
end
```

---

Assuming you have internal knowledge of the `base` class, you could try something like this:

```
module ClassMethods
  def self.extended(base)
    p base.new.method(:superfluous_method).source_location
  end
end

class Foo
  def superfluous_method
  end

  extend ClassMethods
end
```

PS: I am aware this is a giant hack and not very nice, I would be curious to know if there are better ways of doing something like this.

Comment: Nice, though at that point I might as well have the path literally defined for the module instead: `class Foo; FILE_PATH = __FILE__; extend ClassMethods; end`.

Comment: Thanks. If my approach ends up being too painful I'll probably end up swapping it out for something like that. https://github.com/mockdeep/configurator/commit/03f208

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my earlier reply, it was "Yeah, very good point, in that case I would honestly prefer to pass in the filename rather than reaching for the constant."